# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] while calling NEWSAPI through RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest

I am getting the error 'A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]'

while calling NewsAPI using RestTemplate of Spring.

Below is the snippet code I have used to get response. I am able to get the response string but unable to parse it through org.JSON class

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

public class APITest {

    final private static String NEWSAPI_URI="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines";
    final private static String API_TOKEN_VAL=“*****************”;
    final private static String API_TOKEN="apiKey";
    final private static String COUNTYRY="Country";
    final private static String COUNTYRY_VAL="US";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();

        UriComponentsBuilder builder=UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(NEWSAPI_URI)
                .queryParam(API_TOKEN, API_TOKEN_VAL)
                .queryParam(COUNTYRY, COUNTYRY_VAL)
                ;


        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity=restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);


        //parsing responseEntity
        HttpStatus httpStatus=responseEntity.getStatusCode();
        String responseString=responseEntity.getBody();



        System.out.println(responseString);


        if(httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful()) {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(responseString.trim());
            JSONArray articles=jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
            //System.out.println(articles.getJSONObject(0).get("content"));
                for(int it=0;it<articles.length();it++) {
                JSONObject articleObject=articles.getJSONObject(it);
                System.out.println(articleObject.getString("content"));

            }
        }

    }   

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of just throwing the code out there, to help you better try to explain what you have tried so far already and try to make your question a bit clearer. The help can be better te more we know.

Comment: Could you also post the `responseString` so that we can know if you parse it correctly.

Comment: Response string contains ��{"status":"ok","totalResults":37,"articles":[{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Stltoday.com"}....The problem is solved by adding following line ..headers.set("Accept-Charset", "utf-8;");